# keyword arguments during function call

Tags: python

As the definition says it is not legal to follow a keyword argument with a non-keyword argument. Therefore showing an error in first printName function call.

But as far as i know in second function call `reverse= False` is also keyword argument(definition: formals are bound to actuals using the name of the formal parameter)

Now `reverse = False` is also a keyword argument & it follows non-keyword arguments i.e. 'FIRSTLY', 'LASTLY' why it doesn't show error?

```
def printName(first, last, reverse):
        if reverse:
            print last, first
        else:
            print first, last

printName('FIRSTY', last='LASTLY', False)      -----> this shows an error 
printName('FIRSTY', 'LASTLY', reverse= False)  -----> this doesn't why so
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual rule is that, once the keyword arguments are used, they cannot be followed by non-keyword arguments.

The [argument list](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls) is defined in the Python language reference as,

```
argument_list ::=  positional_arguments ["," keyword_arguments]
                     ["," "*" expression] ["," keyword_arguments]
                     ["," "**" expression]
                   | keyword_arguments ["," "*" expression]
                     ["," "**" expression]
                   | "*" expression ["," keyword_arguments] ["," "**" expression]
                   | "**" expression
```

In all these forms, if keyword arguments exist, they are not followed by positional arguments or non-keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Python tries to fill all ordered arguments first, then it checks for keyword arguments. According to the calling convention, ordered arguments are not allowed to follow keyword arguments. This is disallowed because the order would be ambiguous. However there are other more subtle effects of this calling convention. For example, it is possible to double assign to variable names, which leads to the following possible error:

```
def printName(first, last, reverse):
    if reverse:
        print last, first
    else:
        print first, last

printName('FIRSTY', 'LASTLY', last=False)
```

which gives the error:

```
TypeError: printName() got multiple values for keyword argument 'last'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, some concepts:

```
keyword argument <-> function(last = False)
non-keyword argument <-> function(False)
```

Now, the definition:

> *"It is not legal to follow a keyword argument with a non-keyword argument."*

means that a non-keyword argument (e.g. `function(False)`) cannot be *after* a keyword argument (e.g. `last = False`). Therefore, it show the error in that case.

Note that this doesn't match with the function call

```
printName('FIRSTY', 'LASTLY', reverse= False)
```